# Does a code block enclosed in curly brackets return a value from the last function in the block?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

This is part of a code initializing a character driver. See how `class_create` function is used. The returned value `dev_class` is used for the `device_create` function in the next statement.

```
static struct class *dev_class;

static int __init chr_driver_init(void)
{
 ....(skip) ....
/* creating struct class */
if ((dev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "axpu_class")) == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "cannot create the struct class...\n");
    goto r_class;
}

if ((device_create(dev_class, NULL, dev, NULL, "axpu_device")) == NULL) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "cannot create the device ..\n");
    goto r_device;
}
```

I thought this `class_create` is a function, but I just now found this `class_create` is defined like this : in linux-5.4.0/include/linux/device.h

```
/* This is a #define to keep the compiler from merging different
 * instances of the __key variable */
#define class_create(owner, name)       \
({                      \
    static struct lock_class_key __key; \
    __class_create(owner, name, &__key);    \
})
```

I checked the `__class_create` function returns `struct class *` type data.  So if we replace the macro, the original calling code `dev_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "axpu_class")` becomes :

```
dev_class = ({
    static struct lock_class_key __key; \
    __class_create(THIS_MODULE, "axpu_class", &__key);
})
```

So, this means a block of codes enclosed by { and } returns the value that the last statement (or function) returns. I didn't know this type of operation. How is this done and what is the rule?

Comment: It is a GNU extension, not standard C: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html

Comment: Overall, Linux kernel & drivers tend to be very badly written code, relying heavily on gcc non-standard extensions. It's not a place to go look for inspiration.